# project progress linked to strange site in eclipse maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

As I was waiting to complete the Eclipse project progress, it connected to https://www.pramati.com and updated the repo.

How is my project related to Pramati? What kind of stuff is Pramati fetching and what kind of stuff am I fetching from Pramati?

Eclipse version info:

> Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
>   Build id: 20171218-0600

Answer (score 4):

`pramati` ([defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pramati_Technologies)) is shown in [bug 502955](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502955) and referenced in [bug 487917](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487917) "using server wizard results in a bunch of p2 sites being added" fixed in Eclipse 3.8 (so, which Eclipse version are you using?)

```
!MESSAGE Invalid site reference %updateSiteURL in feature com.pramati.eclipse.feature.
```

> even though I never installed pramati.
>
> After initial analysis, I found that similar problem existed when we clicked on "`Download Server Adapter`" in Mars.
>   **Looks like p2 is adding these sites** but now as the link is not available and p2 is visited on the New server Wizard itself,

There is a pending issue on p2 to better managed those sites: [issue 491754](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=491754)

For testing, try a fresh Eclipse installation, referencing a fresh workspace, and then open the same project: there should be no reference to `pramati` there.
Or, your project dependencies through p2 reference a [pramati server](https://www.java-tips.org/java-applications/68-j2ee-server/199-pramati-server.html).

Comment: thank you for your reply, my current eclipse version is Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2),Build id: 20171218-0600 and i did not see Invalid site references.

Comment: bit untechnical of myself but , why my project ever related with pramati, what kind of stuff pramati is fetching and what kind of stuff i am fetching from pramati ?

Comment: @parladneupane not sure, it could be a plugin already installed within Eclipse. (some kind of embedded JEE server)

Comment: ya i thought so,how can we find plugin installed within Eclipse plateform? I am interested.

Comment: @parladneupane The about section (through the menu) should offer a tab with the list of all plugins.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC , i now knew p2 is adding those site and that side referenced to some kind of server or library inside JEE. Still so many things i do not understand here so, i can't accept the answer, it is privilege to upvote. Thank you

Comment: It's now 2020, and using version 2019-12 (4.14.0) it still happens! WTH is Pramati meddling in my eclipse?